# How to store a void* reference to a struct in Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm interacting with some C callbacks that use the standard `void* userdata` method to allow you to store a reference to some context (e.g. a struct). How can I store a reference to a Rust struct in a `void*` and still allow it to be moved around? It seems that Rust moves really are moves, i.e. this code fails (as expected):

```
struct Thing {
    pointer_to_self: *mut Thing,
}

fn create_thing() -> Thing {
    let mut a = Thing {
        pointer_to_self: std::ptr::null_mut(),
    };
    a.pointer_to_self = &mut a as *mut _;
    a
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = create_thing();

    assert_eq!(&mut b as *mut _, b.pointer_to_self);
}
```

Is there a way around this? Can I have a Rust value that doesn't change address when you move it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prevent the value from changing address by heap-allocating the object. This will cost a dereference to access it, but it will be stationary:

```
struct RealThing {
    // ...
}

struct Thing {
    // pointer could also be a field in RealThing, but it seems to
    // make more sense to leave only the actual payload there
    real_thing: Box<RealThing>,
    pointer_to_real: *mut RealThing,
}

fn create_thing() -> Thing {
    let mut a = Thing {
        real_thing: Box::new(RealThing {}),
        pointer_to_real: std::ptr::null_mut(),
    };
    a.pointer_to_real = a.real_thing.as_mut() as *mut _;
    a
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = create_thing();

    assert_eq!(b.real_thing.as_mut() as *mut _, b.pointer_to_real);
}
```

Note that you would have the same issue in C++ if you tried to use the address of an object that has been move- or copy-constructed in the meantime.

A word of warning: actually **using** the pointer will lead to undefined behavior unless one takes precautions to prevent the existence of multiple writable references to the same object. The `UnsafeCell` documentation says:

> In general, transmuting an `&T` type into an `&mut T` is considered undefined behavior. The compiler makes optimizations based on the knowledge that `&T` is not mutably aliased or mutated, and that `&mut T` is unique.

It is probably safer to box `RefCell<RealThing>`, store an immutable pointer to the boxed cell, and convert that back to `&mut RealThing` by casting the pointer to `&RefCell<RealThing>` and calling `borrow_mut()` on the reference. If you then make a mistake, at least Rust will warn you by panicking.