# Why doesn't `move` move referenced data along with the reference?

Tags: rust

This code does not compile...

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = "hi".to_string();
    let wrap = &data;
    std::thread::spawn(move || println!("{}", wrap));
}
```

...because `data` doesn't live inside the spawned thread:

```
error[E0597]: `data` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:3:16
  |
3 |     let wrap = &data;
  |                ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
4 |     std::thread::spawn(move || println!("{}", wrap));
  |     ------------------------------------------------ argument requires that `data` is borrowed for `'static`
5 | }
  | - `data` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Why doesn't Rust move `data` like it does `wrap`? Is there any way to force `data` to be moved along with with `wrap`?

My real code looks more like this. I accept a message, parse it, and then send it to a thread for processing.

```rust
struct Message {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}
let message = Message {
    data: "{\"name\":\"Rust\"}".to_string(),
};

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Parsed<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}
let parsed: Parsed = serde_json::from_slice(&message.data).unwrap();

std::thread::Builder::new()
    .name(parsed.name) // note: need some of the parsed data prior to moving into the thread...so cannot solve with JSON parsing inside thread
    .spawn(move || println("{}", parsed.name));
```

I know I could modify my `Parsed` struct to use `String`s instead of `&'a str`, but this reduces efficiency when the compiler should be able to move `data` just fine.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lifetime of references in closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747620/lifetime-of-references-in-closures)

Comment: To rephrase my question: once I move a reference, I can never make use of the original even if I somehow move it along with the reference?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a rephrasing of the same question. Moving `wrap` has no effect on what you can do with `data`. (Moving or mutating `data` would invalidate `wrap`, though.) The reason for the error message here is because `thread::spawn` requires all references to be `'static`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn't Rust move `data` like it does `wrap`

Several reasons - take your pick:

1. Because `wrap` is captured, not `data`, and the closure moves what is captured.
2. Because the move of `data` would immediately invalidate both `wrap` itself and other references to `data` if they exist. Also, the enclosing scope might itself need `data` for further access.
3. Because then there would be no way to have a closure that captures some values by move and some by reference. Currently you can make a closure `move` but still elect to capture certain values by reference simply by creating an explicit reference and capturing that. The feature you propose would make that impossible.