# Why move closure in rust can't move the ownership of a referenced variable?

Tags: rust, reference, closures, move-semantics, borrow-checker

Here's the example

```
fn call_with_f<F>(f:F) where F: FnOnce(){
    f();
}
struct Vec2{
    x:i32,
    y:i32
}
impl Vec2{
    fn new(x:i32, y:i32) -> Self{
        Self{
            x,
            y
        }
    }
    fn x(&self) -> &i32{
        &self.x
    }
}
fn main() {
    let v = Vec2::new(1,2);
    let rx = v.x();
    call_with_f(move||{
        println!("{}", v.x());
        println!("{}", rx);
    });
}
```

The compiler gives

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `v` because it is borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:88:14
   |
87 |     let rx = v.x();
   |              - borrow of `v` occurs here
88 |     call_with_f(move||{
   |                 ^^^^^^ move out of `v` occurs here
89 |         println!("{}", v.x());
   |                        - move occurs due to use in closure
90 |         println!("{}", rx);
   |                        -- borrow later captured here by closure
```

I know the complaint of compiler, but this case is necessary sometime. In a very complicated
circumstance, a bunch of work need to be done before given into the closure, a reference as an intermediate varible could simplify the preparation. `v` and `rv` have same lifetime at the beginning, they also remain the same lifetime after moved according to the semantics of the move closure. Why?

Comment: No. This is a self-referential closure.

Comment: What do you mean by "`v` and `rv` have same lifetime at the beginning"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot move a borrowed value. Period.

Moreover, such closure cannot exist (safely): it needs to store both the owned value and a reference to (part of) it, i.e. it is [self-referential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct). See [Lifetime of references in closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747620/lifetime-of-references-in-closures).

Depending on your use case, there may be various solutions, ordered from the best to the worst:

- Create the reference inside the closure.
- Don't move the owned value. One of the common reasons people have your question is because they need a `'static` closure for threads. If  this is the case, you may find [scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) helpful.
- Use a crate such as [`owning_ref`](https://crates.io/crates/owning_ref) (unsound!) or [`ourboros`](https://crates.io/crates/ouroboros) (no known sound holes IIRC) to create the self-referential closure. You may need to desugar the closure manually (partially, at least).
- Use `unsafe` code for creating the self referential closure. **WARNING: Do Not Do That Unless You Really Know What You're Doing.**

Comment: Briefly speaking，the reason is the address behind the reference is changed after moving?

Comment: @Lucida Of course the address of a variable is changed after moving. Move is bitwise copy.